# SQLDeveloper will not launch

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've just installed Oracle 11g on Windows, but I can't seem to launch SQLDeveloper. I get the following error: "Windows is searching for SQLDEVELOPER.BAT". To locate the file yourself, click Browse".

I've looked for SQLDEVELOPER.BAT but I can't find it.

I've also tried to launch sqldeveloper.exe directly, but it asks for the path to java.exe. When I browse and select C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe, but then I get the error: Cannot find a J2SE SDK installed at path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7

When I select C:\app\mbergeron\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jre\1.5.0\bin\java.exe I get the same error (Cannot find a J2SE SDK)

When I select C:\app\mbergeron\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdk\bin\java.exe, I get no error. It just goes back to the dialog asking for java.exe

I've tried launching sqldeveloper.exe from the console, but I'm not getting error messages in the console.

Comment: There isn't an `sqldeveloper.bat` unless you write your own. Which version of Java do you have in those two locations? The one that comes with Oracle is certainly compatible, but `sqldeveloper.exe` should run out of the box with that. What happens when you point it at the Oracle version - 'fails to launch' isn't too descriptive. (Maybe run it from a command prompt to see any errors if it's silent?)

Comment: Using `sqldeveloper.exe` is the correct way to start it. What exactly is the error message when you select the Java runtime then? Did you try downloading the SQL Developer package that includes the Java runtime?

Comment: Thanks. When I use sqldevelopper.exe, after I browse and select C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe, the error I get is Cannot find a J2SE SDK installed at path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7

Comment: @eborgner - that's because you're using a JRE, not a JDK. What happens if you point it at `$ORACLE_HOME\jdk\bin\java`?

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I'll got the GitBash route for now as it works fine.

Comment: @Alex Poole. Oh! Thanks, I had not noticed a JDK was needed. Mind you I've tried with the JDK. It still won't launch, but I don't get a error message. It just goes back to the dialog asking for java.exe

Comment: Strange... running from a command prompt might still show an error that the GUI doesn't. You can also set the Java path in `sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf`, in the `SetJavaHome` variable.

Answer (score 3):

-All you have to do is install Gitbash or any Shell interpreter on your windows PC.
Then you have to change the target of the shortcut in the start menu.

Start Menu > Oracle - OraDb11g_home1 > Application Development > SQL Developper -> Properties

CHANGE "Target" By : C:\app\ORACLE_HOME\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper.sh

CHANGE "Start In" By : C:\app\ORACLE_HOME\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper

You can now access SQL Developer, with a direct link from your start menu.

Comment: Thanks! It works nicely (I already had GitBash installed). NOTE: I had to edit C:\app\Philippe\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper.sh to reflect the actual path on my machine. Could you please edit your answer to make it more general, eg: ORACLE_HOME\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper.sh

Comment: Thanks, I was happened because I had gitbash already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Hit this:
Type the full pathname of a J2SE installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in ~/.sqldeveloper/jdk

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the .bat for execution!

On older SQL-Developer Versions (don't know when it changed, but around 4.x), you had to setup the path to jdk at first startup.
Either by editing the product.conf file (Usually under %APPDATA%\sqldeveloper*\product.conf)
or by starting sqldeveloper.exe via commandline. It will ask you then about the path within commandline, and not via GUI. This is the reason, why you should try it via commandline.

Same situation is on UNIX/LINUX.

With newer releases, it has been changed and shouldn't be required anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could just point SQLdeveloper to the java in the oracle folder: (ORACLE_HOME)/jdk/bin/Java.exe